# How to update a document if an array contain values from another array?

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

Assuming the following collection `myCollection`:

```
{
    values: [123, 456, 789],
    name: "name1"
},
{
    values: [123, 543, 654],
    name: "name2"
},
{ 
    values: [456, 876, 098],
    name: "name3"
}
```

how can I update only those documents which `values` contain any value from a given array?

Example:

```
var givenArray = [123, 078, 467];
db.myCollection.update(
    {values:{$in:givenArray}},// <-- here is the problem
    {$set:{updated:true}},
    {multi:true}
);
```

Since `values` is an array, `$in` is not working (of course, and I guess that `.update` alone will not work)

The expected output should be:

```
{
    values: [123, 456, 789],
    name: "name1",
    updated: true
},
{
    values: [123, 543, 654],
    name: "name2",
    updated: true
},
{ 
    values: [456, 876, 098],
    name: "name3"
}
```

**UPDATE**

A solution that works is the following, but it does not seems to be optimum:

```
db.myCollection.find().forEach(function(doc){
  givenArray.forEach(function(item){
    if (doc.values.indexOf(item)>=0) {
      db.myCollection.update(
        {_id:doc._id},
        {
          $set:{updated:true}
        },
        {
          multi:true
        }
      )
    }
  })
})
```

Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to match ALL values of givenArray ?

Comment: No, at least on value should match

Comment: The update works just fine and there is no reason at all to do such looping as you show in a second attempt. I would suggest that you actually did not have the correct inputs or possibly either input or document content actually contained strings that did not match. At any rate, the failure is not reproducible, since I can copy the posted documents and also copy the update statement and receive the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match ALL values of your givenArray, then use $all

```
    {values:{$all:givenArray}}
```

If you want to match ONE value of your givenArray, then use $in (which you did and should work, even if an array, see [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) :  Use the $in Operator to Match Values in an Array)

Answer (score 0):

db.yourColllection.update({values: {$elemMatch: {$in: [123, 078, 467]}}}, {$set: {updated: true}}, {multi: true});
should be an optimal solution you are looking for.